# the number of variables that are repeated 2 or more times in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

I have two forms of data: a `list` (i.e., `r`) and a `data.frame` (i.e., `df`). For each form of data, how can I know the number of variables that are ***repeated 2 or more times*** (in the example below, my **desired output** is: `AA 3 times`, `BB 2 times`, `CC 2 times`)?

**NOTE:** the answer regardless of the form of data, should be the same.

```
r <- list( data.frame( AA = c(2,2,1,1,NA, NA), BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), CC = c(1:5, NA)), # LIST

        data.frame( AA = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), DD = c(1,1,1,2,NA,NA)),

        data.frame( AA = c(1,NA,3,1,NA,NA), BB = c(1,1,1,2,2,NA), CC = c(0:4, NA)) )


df <- do.call(cbind, r)       ## DATA.FRAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a frequency count with `>=` 2 on the `names` of the dataset,

```
tbl <- table(names(df))
tbl1 <- tbl[tbl >=2]
tbl1
#  AA BB CC 
#  3  2  2 

lapply(r, function(x) table(names(x)[names(x) %in% names(tbl1)]))
```

---

If we need it from another answer

```
vec <- names(unlist(r, recursive = FALSE))
nm1 <- unique(vec[duplicated(vec)])
lapply(r, function(x) table(names(x)[names(x) %in% nm1]))
```

Comment: @rnorouzian  In that case, it is easier.  Updated the post

Comment: for r: `tbl <- table(unlist(lapply(r, names)))`.

Comment: @rnorouzian  Isn't this based on `df` only (as per your previous questions, we shouldn't consider `r`)?

Comment: @rnorouzian  What about the suggestion by lmo

Comment: @rnorouzian   After that `tbl[tbl >=2]`

Comment: @rnorouzian  I am confused.  You want the frequency or names?.  The answer you linked is based on duplicated alone and doesn't take into consideration the frequency based

Comment: @rnorouzian  You meant from the `tbl` created with `df` ?